# struct mapping in ink substrate

Tags: solidity, substrate, rust-ink

**In solidity we can do the mapping of structure like this**

```
struct BookEntry {
        string bookId;
        string bookName;
        string authorName;
        bool released;
    }

  mapping (string => BookEntry) keyval;
```

**and set the values corresponding to bookId like this**

```
function setBook(string memory bookId, string memory bookName, string memory authorName) public returns(string memory){
   keyval[bookId].bookId = bookId;
   keyval[bookId].bookName = bookName;
   keyval[bookId].authorName = authorName;
   keyval[bookId].released = true;
   return bookId;
}
```

**How can this structure be mapped in ink substrate contract?**

```
#[ink::contract]
mod btc_new {

    use ink_prelude::string::String;

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct BookEntry {
        book_id: String,
        book_name: String,
        author_name: String,
        is_released: bool,
        
    }
```